# Advance new file in sublime text 2

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, text-editor

I have beed using **[Advance new file](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile)** package in Sublime Text 2 and when I press shortcut for creating new file is in my main directory `C\users\%name\`.

Is it possible (or with another package) to set path to be in folder that I'm currently at.

Example, if I'm at

```
C:\Users\%user\Desktop\Notebook\Ruby programs\Ruby\test.rb
```

to set the path to

```
C:\Users\Bane\Desktop\Notebook\Ruby programs\Ruby\
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> AdvancedNewFile -> Settings - User` and add the following to the file.

`{"default_root": "current"}`

You can see more about settings on the [GitHub](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile#settings) page.